# Tornado Server returns 404 when request contains full url instead of path only

Tags: python, tornado

A Standard HTTP request has the request line structured as such:

```
GET /some/path HTTP/1.1
```

With a RequestHandler initialized at "/some/path" it processes these requests.

However my server is receiving some requests where the URI path includes the host domain:

```
GET http://example.com/some/path HTTP/1.1
```

Although the URI (a.k.a. the path, "/some/path") is the same, Tornado does not recognize the matching path and returns a 404.  After searching high and low I am still not able to find a fix for this.

How can Tornado be configured to process these requests?

Comment: What user-agent is sending the complete URL in the GET? I'm fairly certain that this breaks the protocol specification.

Comment: I don't have that information but did reproduce the issue using telnet, so it occurs independent of what User-Agent is set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tornado does not currently support this style of request ([#1036](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1036)), and there are no easy workarounds.

This style of request is valid according to RFC 2616, although it is normally only used when connecting to an HTTP proxy. Using a load balancer such as nginx *may* be able to convert requests like this to the more universally-supported `GET /some/path HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n` (I've rarely seen the proxy-style requests in the wild; I'm not sure if that's because I normally use `nginx` or if there are other factors at work).